# Insert Row if cell contains "&"

Tags: excel, vba

Probably something simple I've missed, but I need to run down a column, and copy-insert any rows that have a "&" in the cell.

I've managed to get it to here, but it's now just getting stuck on the very first cell with a "&", and won't move past it.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Working")

Dim rng As Range

On Error Resume Next

ws.Range("A2").Select

Do Until ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0) = Empty
    If InStr(ActiveCell, "&") <> 0 Then GoTo InsertRow Else
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop

InsertRow:
    Set rng = ActiveCell.Rows
    rng.Rows.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
    ActiveCell.Offset(2, 0).Select
    Resume Next
```

There could be blanks in the column, but I can edit that later, so long as the macro can actually run past the first cell, we'll be fine. There are no error messages, as it just sticks to the first cell that contains a "&".

[image: Before]

[image: After]

That's the before and after, the second image shows the rows being copied out.

Comment: Can you describe your end goal a little bit with some sample data? You can most likely also avoid using .Select

Comment: @JvdV
Some of the cells in the column could be John & Karen Jane, Martin Edward & Lauren, Paul, Fraser & Sarah, and variants of. I basically just need to copy and paste the entire row, so that there are two rows wherever there is a &, so the three examples would be copies, but Paul wouldn't be. Does that make a bit more sense?

Comment: Well, it's best to demonstrate your goal in your actual question. Screenshots, markdown sample data, expected output etc. Putting it in your comment is not very helpful

Comment: Hard to know what you want to do without examples of data, before and after.  But code errors:  No reason for `On Error`.  `Resume` is only applicable in the setting of a trapped Error, so your insertrow never returns.  either include it inline, or make it a callable sub. Also you should not be using `Select` and `ActiveCell`.  Search SO for an article on how to avoid it.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Thanks for letting me know about screenshots, I'll make sure to use them if I have any other questions. I've added a couple, a before and after of what I need, hope that helps

Comment: You don't have iteration variable. Moreover, the loop must be from bottom to top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- no Select, Activate, ActiveCell, etc
- no OnError
- no Resume
- iterate from bottom to top

---

```
Option Explicit
Sub dupAmps()
    Dim WS As Worksheet, C As Range
    Dim LR As Long
    Dim I As Long
Set WS = Worksheets("sheet1")
With WS
    LR = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
End With

For I = LR To 2 Step -1
    Set C = WS.Cells(I, 1)
    If InStr(C, "&") > 0 Then
        C.EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlDown
        C.EntireRow.Copy C.Offset(-1, 0)
    End If
Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: @C.Fsh Depending on the size of the database, you may want to turn off `ScreenUpdating` and set calculation to manual for speed issues.